# kotlin global activity View reference to use in fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, view, global

I'm creating a podcast app with a single activity consisting of 2 elements:

- NavHostFragment
- ExoPlayerView (in this case just the PlayerControlView with Id exoplayer_view)

I would like to set up a global variable with a reference to the exoplayer view, so I can use this variable within my fragments and attached viewmodels to play/stop/load audio. How would I implement this efficiently in kotlin?

Right now, whenever I need the exoplayer within a fragment I recreate an variable like this:

```
var exoplayerView = (activity as MainActivity).exoplayer_view
```

By setting up a global variable in the activity, I don't have to do this again and again all over the app. This is also probably less memory exhaustive than creating another reference in every fragment/viewmodel.

MainActivity:

```
...
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // global reference to use for all fragments, viewmodels and helper classes
    var exoplayerView: PlayerControlView = exoplayer_view

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        ....
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        releasePlayer(exoplayer_view)
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
class TracksFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        ...
        // make use of exoplayer reference within the fragment and/or viewmodel
        // the exoplayerView variable can not be recognised here
        if(exoplayerView.player==null) exoplayerView.player = viewModel.player
        ...

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

I thought by setting up the exoplayerView reference like this I would be able to reach it from my fragment. However it doesn't. How could I do something like this in a efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views shouldn't be accessed 'globally' liked that, try to think of Activities and Fragments as enclosed modules whose internal functionalities are hidden away and protected by public facing interfaces.

Here's one approach that was recommended before shared ViewModels became a thing:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Basically you can have your Activity implement some kind of interface that represents the functionality you want to be accessible to the child fragments.   The fragments then access this by casting the Activity instance it has to a variable of that interface type.  This allows you to call that method directly in the Fragment.

A better approach uses a shared ViewModel between the Activities and Fragments.  You can have the ViewModel expose observable fields or LiveData that can be set and observed by these Activities and Fragments.  For example you can have a field in the ViewModel that represents the state of that player.  Some user action in the Fragment can can set the value of that field and an observer in the Activity can trigger some behaviour in the player.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It helped me out a lot. [This medium article](https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activity-using-viewmodel-ca733233a51c) also helped me set up my sharedviewmodel attached to the activity. Ironically, I already had an activity viewmodel ;')